# How to solve this recurrence relation of degree 3?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm just wondering how to do this problem. I know I have to make the characteristic equation. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The corresponding characteristic equation is
$$x^3-2x^2-5x+6 = 0$$
$x-1$ is a factor clearly. Hence,
$$(x^3-2x^2-5x+6) = (x-1)(x^2-x-6) = (x-1)(x-3)(x+2)$$
Hence, the solution to your recurrence is of the form
$$a_n = c_1\cdot 1^n + c_2\cdot (-2)^n + c_3 \cdot 3^n$$
Fix $c_1,c_2,c_3$ using the initial conditions.

Comment: Heh, beat me to it. +1

Comment: is it -2x or -2x^2? since 2 is with 2an-1... isn't that just 2x?

Comment: @ralph $-2x^2$ is correct.